# How to get image source attribute value from img html tag in c#?

Tags: c#, html

My string variable stores set of HTML Tags along with img source file link.

```
string str = "<div> <img src="https://i.testimg.com/images/g/test/s-l400.jpg" style="width: 100%;"> <div>Test</div> </div>"
```

How to get the src attribute value from the string str. Apparently, i will have to assign the value of src to another variable.

How to get src attribute value from img html tag in c#?

Comment: If you have a HTML source, you can write the HTML to a [HtmlDocument](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument) class. This class returns all the Images in the Document as the `Images` collection. For each image reference in the collection, you can write: `var src = images[Index].GetAttribute("href");`. It will return the `src="..."` content. The `<img>` element doesn't define the position of the `src` attribute inside the tag. Nor the actual content. You'ld need to build a more complex parser to handle the edge cases. Since there's one already built...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will extract the value of the `src` attribute.

```
string str = "<div> <img src=\"https://i.testimg.com/images/g/test/s-l400.jpg\" style=\"width: 100%;\"> <div>Test</div> </div>";

// Get the index of where the value of src starts.
int start = str.IndexOf("<img src=\"") + 10;

// Get the substring that starts at start, and goes up to first \".
string src = str.Substring(start, str.IndexOf("\"", start) - start);
```

Comment: thanks very helpful... for learning .. why you are adding + 10 to the indexof syntax? that will help me to understand as well..

Comment: @goofyui - `+ 10` is because `IndexOf()` returns the index where the string `("<img src=\""` starts, and the `src` attribute value starts after `("<img src=\""` whose length is `10`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegularExpressions

```
Regex("<img\\s+src\\s*=\\s*\"(.*?)\"", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

in results: 
first group (index 0) - Full match
second group (index 1) - group 1 - (.*?) - link what you want

test regex online you can [here](https://regex101.com/r/zITVHD/1)

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string src = "";
        Regex Pattern = new Regex("<img\\s+src\\s*=\\s*\"(.*?)\"", RegexOptions.Multiline);
        string str = "<div> <img src=\"https://i.testimg.com/images/g/test/s-l400.jpg\" style=\"width: 100%;\"> <div>Test</div> </div>";
        var res = Pattern.Match(str);
        if (res.Success)
        {
            src = res.Groups[1].Value;          
        }
        Console.WriteLine(src);
    }
}
```

Comment: if add some spaces in `"<img src=\""` like `"<img  src = \""` IndexOf return "-1",  
when img tag always static IndexOf is good way

Comment: i mean if str change `"<div> <img src = \"https://i.testimg.com/images/g/test/s-l400.jpg\" ...` str.IndexOf("<img src=\"") don't find what you want